# Stopping Elasticsearch service removes category products in 2.4

Tags: elasticsearch, magento2.4

I was curious what would happen if I stopped the Elasticsearch service in Magento 2.4. What I found I cant seem to understand.

When the service is stopped it empties all the categories. I would have assumed Elasticsearch was for the mini search/advanced search not the catalog listings.

Can anyone confirm if this is by design or is there a bug in Magento 2.4? Also any ideas on how to fix this?

My setup is Magento 2.4 on Valet (MacOs/PHP 7.3.20). I installed Elasticsearch via Homebrew.

**Elasticsearch running**
[image: With Elasticsearch running]

**Elasticsearch stopped**
[image: With Elasticsearch stopped]

Comment: elastic search is used for all catalog search functions including product category lists and filtering. Disabling it in 2.4 is not an option...

Comment: One question apart from your issue, I’m not able to install using valet plus, what ES version you using ? I’m getting error while installing.

Comment: @SudhanshuBajaj I am using Valet not Valet Plus. ES is version 7.8.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ElasticSearch is in charge of the entire catalog and search, provisioning the data to Magento 2.4.

ElasticSearch is a requirement in Magento 2.4, as you can see in the page [Magento 2.4 technology stack requirements](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html), so it never can be disabled like in Magento 2.3.

I recommend to set the services to auto-restart in a production server, so if ElasticSearch or MySQL service goes down, it will restart automatically. You can do it in Docker using the parameter below.

```
docker run --restart=always
```

Comment: Thank you for confirming this is by design. I was aware it was a requirement but assume it was for search only.

Comment: gah that's annoying - i have a third party search already setup on my M2 - but now I have to get a whole java stack on top no matter what?

Comment: you can set up your search engine as the main search engine instead of ElasticSearch. @iphigenie

Comment: Thanks @RafaelCorrêaGomes I had undestood you could not even upgrade to M2.4 without a configured elastic search. I guess I'll do a test run